# page not refreshing after router push vue js

Tags: laravel, vue.js

after router push page not refreshing. then i have use this code
<button @click="$router.push('/student/'+student.uuid+'/fee/'+student_record.id).then(() => {
window.location.reload()})">Click to Navigate but not working this too. what to do?

Answer (score 0):

if you managing your routes with name in separate file like router.js then you can use below code with required parameters to route your view.

```
<button :to="{ name: 'projects.create' }" class="rounded-full text-center pt-1" pill > click </button>
```

or you can use simply

```
<a :href="`/projects/${project.id}/environments/${ env.id }`" ="text-dark">
```